# Is it possible to calculate the total sum within partition and cumulative sum between partitions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, teradata

I am interested in calculating a descending cumulative sum based on groups, however, I want the cumulative sum to be based on the grouping. In other words, I want the total sum within a group and cumulative sum to be between the groups, the order of group_id is important.

For example, using the sample data below:

```
group_id    Value
1           5
1           5
1           5
2           5
2           2
2           4
3           1
3           2
3           3
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
group_id    Value   CumSum
3           1       6
3           2       6
3           3       6
2           5       17
2           2       17
2           4       17
1           5       32
1           5       32
1           5       32
```

I have tried using a partition and then ordering on the group_id, however it does not appear to work, any assistance would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE data (group_id INT, value INT)
insert into data values 
(1,5),
(1,5),
(1,5),
(2,5),
(2,2),
(2,4),
(3,1),
(3,2),
(3,3);

-- My Attempt:
select *, sum(value) over(partition by group_id order by group_id, value) as cum_sum
from data;
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Teradata <> SQL Server - why have you tagged both?

Comment: In your sample results, you put group 3 first, then group 2, then group 1. Is this ordering important? Especially since groups 1 and 3 just _happen_ to have the same sum.

Comment: @DaleK I am interested in Teradata, however I have added sql server since I am hoping I can translate it to Teradata.  Also, I will update the question so that it does not include images. Thank yo

Comment: @AaronBertrand The ordering for the final result was intentional.

Comment: @nwaldo Ok, so is it simply `ORDER BY group_id DESC` or is there other information that we don't know about that specifies that order? If there is other information that guides this output (since your question doesn't mention the importance of order at all), could you share it? And could you change your sample data so that all three groups have different sums?

Comment: You don't currently provide enough information to order it the way you want it...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you, I have updated the data so each group sum is different.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible.
No partition in the SUM OVER, just an order by group_id.

> ```
> select *
> , [CumSum] = sum(value) over(order by group_id desc)
> from data
> order by group_id desc;
> ```

| group_id | value | CumSum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 | 17 |
| 2 | 2 | 17 |
| 2 | 4 | 17 |
| 1 | 2 | 23 |
| 1 | 3 | 23 |
| 1 | 1 | 23 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=687f7e09eca8bf27c3abb3df8d49f9b4)*

Comment: I had [something similar](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a45765f849dcd7718080252ac413f689) on the go but the order was unclear.

Comment: Must have been close. Well, it's unsure atm, since his example sql wasn't descending.

Comment: Right, well the first screen shot shows 1,2,3 then the desired results show 3,2,1. (But I have no idea if that was intentional ... I was just mentioning that's why I gave up.) :-)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use `row_number()` to find the first row in each `group_id`, and sum the `value` for the group. Then build a cumulative sum with the help of a CTE.

```
with cte as (
    select *
        , sum([value]) over (partition by group_id) cum_sum
        , row_number() over (partition by group_id order by group_id) group_row
    from #data
)
select group_id, [value]
    , sum(case when group_row = 1 then cum_sum else 0 end) over (order by group_id) cum_sum
from cte
order by group_id;
```

Comment: `SUM()` has a quirky behavior - to me at least, trying to find some bona fide documentation for it, because [it doesn't seem to be mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) - where `OVER` without `PARTITION BY` will act like `DISTINCT` instead of `ALL` against the column(s) referenced in `ORDER BY`. So it returns the same `SUM` for the `group_id` without over-counting and without the complexity of picking out a single row per group. (+1 because this still gets the right answer, I think, depending on order which would be easy to fix...

Comment: ...and also because it's how I would have solved it if I wasn't aware of the quirk (or have just totally forgotten that aspect of relational algebra).

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're thinking of `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` as a default, rather than `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` which is what most people would expect ([fully documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#order-by)), trips a lot of people up. However that's not relevant where there is no `ORDER BY`, so it only applies to the second `SUM` here.

Comment: @Charlieface Did you look at the other answer (which produces the right result without `PARTITION BY`)? That's the one I'm talking about. Instinctively you would think partition would be needed there for it not to be a simple running total.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No I didn't look at it properly, yes I think this is the only situation I've ever seen that `RANGE` was actually wanted

Answer (score 0):

@LukStorms solution will not work as expected in Teradata, because it doesn't support RANGE and thus not Standard SQL's default of RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING when there's ORDER BY (it defaults to a GROUP Sum instead).

Different logic to Dale K's answer:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT group_id, value
      -- cumulative sum per group
     ,SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY group_id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cumsum
   FROM data
 )
SELECT group_id, value
   -- max per group
  ,MAX(cumsum) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)
FROM cte;
```